# Recursively remove and replace items in clojure

Tags: replace, clojure

My problem is removing an item from a list and replacing it with a new value.
For example, if I had the list `'(F J (N R D A))`, and I wanted to replace it with a brand new list such as `'(F J (M G E Q F))`. So I would be removing the innermost list and replacing it with a new one. Any advice?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Is your purpose to replace whole inner list, or every item in inner list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clojure.walk` to recursively replace elements of a data structure:

```
(def my-list '(F J (N R D A)))
(walk/postwalk
  #(if (= '(N R D A) %)
     '(M G E Q F)
     %)
  my-list)
=> (F J (M G E Q F))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(replace {'(N R D A) '(M G E Q F)} '(F J (N R D A))) => (F J (M G E Q F))
```